# Is there a Java way to write code like "Python's underscore for loop"?

Tags: java, python, loops, for-loop

I just saw a post about Python's loop: [Trying to understand Python loop using underscore and input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39188827/trying-to-understand-python-loop-using-underscore-and-input)

There's a way to loop in python without "variable name":

```
for _ in range(10):
    print("Hello world")
```

A Java way to do it:

```
for (int _ = 0; _ < 10; _++) {
    System.out.println("Hello world");
}
```

And eclipse warns me:

> '_' should not be used as an identifier, since it is a reserved
>   keyword from source level 1.8 on.

Maybe I should just stick to `i` and write

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    System.out.println("Hello world");
}
```

which use a (maybe) not necessary integer variable.

Is there another way to write simple java loop like python loop, maybe more elegantly?

Comment: isn't `_` just another variable name as well? It's even *explicitly mentioned* in the comments and answers to that question.

Comment: When I use `_` I got warning from eclipse "'_' should not be used as an identifier, since it is a reserved keyword from source level 1.8 on." but I should check out this first for `_` anyway.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23523946/underscore-is-a-reserved-keyword

Comment: The `_` is a variable name, but it's conventional to use it when the loop index isn't used in the loop body. Also note that `_` has a special meaning in the interactive interpreter - it holds the result of the last expression that wasn't assigned to a variable.

Comment: I think I should close this as `_` is not necessarily a good way of writing code according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893163/

Comment: FWIW, Nick Coghlan is a major core Python developer, so he knows what he's talking about. ;) But if you aren't doing i18n stuff then using `_` is perfectly fine and it makes it clear to readers that the loop index isn't used in the loop body.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no more efficient or more elegant (IMO) way to express the loop in Java.

However:

- The supposed efficiency of `_` in Python could well be an illusion.
- The supposed inefficiency of an unused variable in Java is probably an illusion.  The JIT compiler should optimize away any assignments to the variable that do not contribute to the computation.
- We are talking about a **tiny** overhead compared to the `println` call, and all of the stuff that that causes.

---

One more point.  The identifier `_` is legal in Java 8, but it is a blatant style violation.  In Java 9, (I think) they are going to make it a syntax error!!

Comment: Elegance is always a matter of opinion!!

Comment: In Python, _ has zero effect on the efficiency of the code execution, but it improves efficiency of humans reading the code, assuming they're familiar with the convention.

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8+, you could use an `IntStream` and something like

```
IntStream.range(0, 10).forEach(i -> System.out.println("Hello, World"));
```

Comment: Yes ... but you still effectively have a loop variable (`i`).  And this would be less efficient than a plain for loop (with a regular loop variable).

Comment: @StephenC Sure, but it's arguably the most elegant, as it's more readable.

Comment: @4castle - See my comment on my Answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

According to the post and its answer, the '_' in a python loop is a "throwaway" variable, which means the value is not important / used in the loop.

I think your java loop is the same with your python loop, '_' or 'i' doesn't bring any diff.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a helper function will do

```
IntConsumer c(Runnable f) {
    return ($) -> f.run();
}
```

and run the code with

```
IntStream.range(0, 10).forEach(c(() -> System.out.println("hi")));
```

Downside is, for each type of consumer you need to have a helper function since this won't work as IntConsumer is not a Function:

```
private <T1, T2> Function<T1, T2> c(Runnable f) {
    return ($) -> { f.run(); return null; }
}
```