# Underscore "_" in for loop

Tags: python-3.x

I was check a solution on hacker rank where i was solving a question asking to print the name of the person with the second highest score from an input which has to be converted to a nested list first .

I understood all the logic in the code and most part of the code but why the Underscore ( _ ) in the for loop .Please explain me the code if there is a different concept .

```
marksheet = []
for _ in range(0,int(input())):
    marksheet.append([input(), float(input())])

second_highest = sorted(list(set([marks for name, marks in marksheet])))[1]
print('\n'.join([a for a,b in sorted(marksheet) if b == second_highest]))
```

Comment: tried googling your title and got this result in the first page [Trying to understand Python loop using underscore and input](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39188827/995714)

Answer (score 7):

It's a Pythonic convention to use underscore as a variable name when the returning value from a function, a generator or a tuple is meant to be discarded.

In your example, the code inside the `for` loop does not make any use of the values generated by `range(0,int(input()))`, so using an underscore makes sense as it makes it obvious that the loop does not intend to make use of it.