# Is there an equivalient of `(void)foo` in Python?

Tags: python

In various languages `(void)foo` is used to note that the variable `foo` is not used instead of forgotten, especially when writing a callback function whose arguments are restricted by other functions, like

```c
static int callback(const char *path, void *buf, fuse_fill_dir_t filler,
                    off_t offset, struct fuse_file_info *fi)
{
    (void) offset;
    (void) fi;
...
```

How can this be properly done in Python? Say, when iterating a table by rows and there is an unneeded column `func`, what is the Python manner of claming that `func` is not demanded here? Code below:

```py
for no, msg, func in TABLE:
    print(f'[{no}] {msg}')
```

Comment: For future visitors: [PEP 640 -- Unused variable syntax](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0640/)

Comment: (which mentions not only `_` but also the less-famous `?`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the underscore, which pretty much serves the purpose you're thinking of.

In the following example, `_` indicates that the variable is not important in the loop.

```py
for _ in range(10):
     print("Hello world")
```

[You can take a look at this question for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39188827/trying-to-understand-python-loop-using-underscore-and-input)